# Capacitor value for this motor

Tags: capacitor, induction-motor, conversion

[image]I have the motor in the picture. In the triangle connection, what is the cap-s value in order to get it running ok?
Same, is there any formula / calculus for this situation (triphase motor running on monophase).

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do you intend to run a three phase motor on single phase?

Comment: Yes, that is the intention.

Comment: Sort of, thank you. If not enough, I-ll ask more.

Comment: Actually, I hoped for a ready made solution, maybe from somebody who did it and tested it, to tell me XXuF. Still searching.

Comment: Are you aware of the drawbacks of this method?

Comment: @winny: Like? Not really.

Comment: Very low starting torque, general derating of the motor, high current though the capacitor which will eventually wear out along with the motor unless you have protection kicking in. You're better off selling it and getting yourself a single phase motor or a VFD with single phase input and three phase output.